# question is can I put 27.5 rims/tires in place of the 29ers

Tags: tire, bike-fit

I currently have a motobecane 29er, and it is to tall and beyond time i can exchance it, question is can I put 27.5 rims/tires in place of the 29ers

Comment: Does it have disc or rim brakes?

Comment: Consider that  you only lower the bike by half the difference.  1.5 inches is 38mm but half of that comes off the top, so the axles only get 19mm lower.  Have you lowered the seatpost and saddle yet ?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with smaller wheels? Sure, it will slightly improve standover-height, but that’s usually not the problem when you ride a too-big frame/bike. The big problem is usually the bike being too long despite already using a short stem.